# Sample dataframe with number of records sampled per hour predefined

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, random

I have to sample a dataframe (df1) and I have another dataframe (df2) that tells me how many records I should retrieve from each hour of the day.

For example,
df1:

```
   Hour number
0.  00    A
1.  00    B
2.  00    C
3.  01    D
4.  01    A
5.  01    B
6.  01    D
```

df2:

```
   Hour number
0.  00    1
1.  01    2
```

So that in the end, I would get for example, record number 1 for midnight and records 3 and 5 for 1 am (or any other combination so long as it respects the number in df2)

The thing is that I need to write this in a function in order for me to call this inside another function.

So far I have

```
def sampling(frame):
     return np.random.choice(frame.index)
```

but I am failing to add the constraints of the df2.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we add the number of samples required as a new column using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and the apply [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to each group of `Hour` values. Finally we remove the added column by returning all but the last column:

```
def sampling(df1, df2):
    return df1.merge(df2, on='Hour').groupby('Hour').apply(lambda x: x.sample(x.Number[0])).reset_index(0,True).iloc[:,:-1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Hour': [0,0,0,1,1,1,1], 'Value': list('ABCDABD')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Hour': [0,1], 'Number': [1,2]})
sampling(df1, df2)
```

Result:

```
   Hour Value
2     0     C
4     1     A
5     1     B
```